# what's the signature of C++ deleter?

Tags: c++, delegates, signature

Since C++ 11, shared_ptr or unique_ptr constructor can have two paramters, with the 2nd a deleter.
I'm interested in how this deleter is defined.

**Some [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/unique_ptr) only mentions the return type of the deleter**:

```
unique_ptr( pointer p, /* see below */ d1 );  //(3) (since C++11)
unique_ptr( pointer p, /* see below */ d2 );  //(4) (since C++11)
```

3-4) Constructs a std::unique_ptr object which owns p, initializing the stored pointer with p and initializing a deleter D as below (depends upon whether D is a reference type)

a) If D is non-reference type A, then the signatures are:

```
unique_ptr(pointer p, const A& d);  //(requires that Deleter is  nothrow-CopyConstructible) 
unique_ptr(pointer p, A&& d); // (requires that Deleter is nothrow-MoveConstructible)
```

b) If D is an    lvalue-reference type A&, then the signatures are:

```
unique_ptr(pointer    p, A& d); 
unique_ptr(pointer p, A&& d);
```

c) If D is an    lvalue-reference type const A&, then the signatures are:

```
unique_ptr(pointer p, const A& d); 
unique_ptr(pointer p, const A&&  d);
```

**But, referring to [Stanley B. Lippman's "C++ Primer", 5th edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321714113), there seems are more restrictions**: in Ch 12 Dynamic Memory, Sec 12.1, pg 469:

```
void end_connection(connection *p) { disconnect(*p); }

void f(destination &d /* other parameters */)
{
connection c = connect(&d);
shared_ptr<connection> p(&c, end_connection);
// use the connection
// when f exits, even if by an exception, the connection will be properly closed
}
```

Here end_connection is the deleter, however, there's an implicit requirement, that the first parameter of the deleter(namely "*p"), and the first parameter of the shared_ptr constructor (namely "c"), has the same type (namely "connection").

**Is this observation true? that if the deleter need be more strictly defined, the signature is more complex?**

---

**Update after Alan Stokes's reply**

The deleter for

```
shared_ptr<A>
```

could be defined as

```
function<B (A *)> deleter;
```

, where function is the template defined in "functional" header, and B could be anything as the return type of a deleter does not matter.

So the constructor of

```
shared_ptr<A>
```

could be written as

```
shared_ptr<A> p(A *, function<B (A *)> )
```

I guess the "concept lite" is introduced due to the arbitrary choice of B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's plenty of info at the reference you cite:

"The object is destroyed ... by calling Deleter(ptr)."

"Deleter must be ... callable with an argument of type unique_ptr::pointer".

These constraints are not enforced by the type system so are not technically part of the signature, but are specified as requirements of `unique_ptr`.

Comment: Understand. Nevertheless, is it possible to define in signature so that compiler can report misuse ?

Comment: Not yet. (The ability to do so requires Concepts, which are not currently part of the standard, although that may change.) Misuse will probably still be detected (the call to the deleter won't compile), but the error message may not be very helpful.

Comment: I don't think so. The original proposal is described at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concepts_%28C%2B%2B%29; you can get more information on the current state of the idea at http://isocpp.org/blog/2013/02/concepts-lite-constraining-templates-with-predicates-andrew-sutton-bjarne-s.